# MLE and MOM estimates coincide in Normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, maximum-likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let $(X_1,Y_1),...,(X_n,Y_n)$ be a sample form $N(\mu_x,\mu_y,\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\rho)$ population. If $n\geq 5$ and $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ are unknown, I want to conclude that the estimates of all five parameters from MLE would coincide with the method of moments estimates.

For MOM, I got:
$$\mu_x=\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{k=1}^nX_i=\bar{X}\quad \quad \mu_y=\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{k=1}^nY_i=\bar{Y}$$
$$\sigma^2_x=\frac{1}{n}(\Sigma_{k=1}^nX_i-\bar{X})^2\quad \quad \sigma^2_y=\frac{1}{n}(\Sigma_{k=1}^nY_i-\bar{Y})^2$$
$$\rho=\frac{\Sigma_{k=1}^n X_kY_k-\bar{X}\bar{Y}}{\sqrt{\Sigma_{k=1}^n(X_k-\bar{X})^2(Y_k-\bar{Y})^2}}$$

I know a corollary related to this, which would show that the MLE of $\theta$ is unique.

> Consider the exponential family:
> $$p(x,\theta)=h(x)exp(\Sigma_{j=1}^kc_j(\theta)T_j(x)-B(\theta)), x\in
> > X, \theta\in\Theta$$ Let $C^0$ denote the interior of the range of
> $(c_1(\theta),...,c_k(\theta))^T$ and let $x$ be the observed data. If
> the equations $E_{\theta}T_j(X)=T_j(x), j=1,...,k$ have a solution
> $\hat{\theta}(x)\in C^0$, then it is the unique MLE of $\theta$.

Also, because $(X_1,Y_1)$ has a density, we can assume that $\hat{\sigma_x^2}>0,\hat{\sigma_y^2}>0,|\hat{\rho}|<1$, where
$$\hat{\sigma_x^2}=\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_x)^2\quad\quad \hat{\sigma_y^2}=\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\mu_y)^2$$
$$\hat{\rho}=\frac{1}{n\hat{\sigma_x^2}\hat{\sigma_y^2}}\Sigma_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_x)(Y_i-\mu_y)$$
These are derived under the assumption that the means are known.

I want to show that the estimates of $\mu_x,\mu_y,\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\rho$ by MLE, when the means are unknown coincide with the estimates by MOM.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: please clarify your question, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I added one line near the end, specifically addressing what I'm looking for. @LucasRoberts

Comment: thanks, there also seems to be a mismatch of assumptions, if I understand correctly the MLE assumes the means are known yet the MOM does not. If the assumptions aren't the same between the two estimation approaches it will be difficult to show equivalence of means.

Comment: In the MLE as well, I assumed that the means are unknown. @LucasRoberts